# MassTransit IEndpointRegistrationConfigurator dynamic names

Tags: c#, asp.net, masstransit

Good morning,

I have multiple (Micro-services) REST APIs that use MassTransit to either connect to RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus depending on the environment.

When the applications starts they configure MassTransit service and register the consumers, my question is do we need to Generate random names on configuring the endpoints? I am currently generating a random name by using the consumer name and then a random Guid. When I look at the administration I have approx 3500+ queues and 3500+ exchanges I guess this is due to when the application starts or get redeployed. This can be seen on my Dev machine when I have a local container running RabbitMQ.

The message types rarely get changed and therefore I am thinking that generating this random endpoint name is causing these number of queues. If I was to see that this to standard name per type of consumer would i see any issues?

The code is similar to below:

```
private static void RegisterAllConsumers(this IBusRegistrationConfigurator cfg)
{
   cfg.AddConsumer<SuperSimpleConsumer>().Endpoint(
     e => e.ConfigureEndpoint(nameof(SuperSimpleConsumer)));
}

private static void ConfigureEndpoint(this IEndpointRegistrationConfigurator e, string consumerName)
{
    e.Name = $"{consumerName}_{GuidHelper.GenerateStringIdFromGuid()}";
    e.Temporary = false;
}
```

So for example if I was to just change to

```
private static void ConfigureEndpoint(this IEndpointRegistrationConfigurator e, string consumerName)
{
   e.Name = consumerName;
   e.Temporary = false;
}
```

Or maybe another option is to set them to Temporary = True

FYI I am using MassTransit v8.0.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cover all the settings in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsUlQ93j2MY) and explain how to customize the endpoint.

If you could update your question to actually explain what you're trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it. For instance, if you just want to fan out events to consumers in each instance, use the `InstanceId` property of the endpoint configurator, and set `Temporary=true` to have it automatically deleted.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do (Fan out). In the background I have just tested using the configuration while waiting for an answer and it works perfectly. The name is set the consumer and temporary to true, then set the InstanceId to the existing name mechanism. https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration gave me all the information. I should have read the manual!